# How do I get a resource from an Angular.js module for a jasmine test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a module that contains resources for a project, and the code looks like this:

**editor_services.js**

```
var editorServices = angular.module('editorServices', ['ngResource']);
editorServices.factory('Project', ['$resource', '$http',function($resource, $http){ 
//...etc
```

now I would like to write tests for a controller that expects a project resource as an argument. How can I get an instance of the project resource that is created by this factory out of the `editorServices` variable?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working example how one would test Resources (or http) in angular
http://plnkr.co/edit/kK5fDFIVpyZTInH1c6Vh?p=preview

The basic setup is:

1. load `angular-mocks.js` in your test. This replaces the `$httpBackend` with mock version. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend
2. In your test call `$httpBackend.expect()` to create expectation to be mocked out.
3. When you want to simulate server response call `$httpBackend.flush()`
4. There is a caveat that normal `.toEqual()` from jasmine dose not work with `$resource` so you have to create custom matcher like so:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.addMatchers({
      // we need to use toEqualData because the Resource hase extra properties 
      // which make simple .toEqual not work.
      toEqualData: function(expect) {
        return angular.equals(expect, this.actual);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: In your example, if I pass `{id: 1}` to `Projects.query` [test fails](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Rig6CBp3F2C0aHnd5ci?p=preview).
Is there a way to expect GET request no matter with or without GET params? I see only `regexp` as solution, but it looks dirty..