# How to mock an angular $resource object in Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a jasmine test that fails that way :

```
Expected spy save to have been called with
[ Object({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'})]
 but actual calls were
[ Resource({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'})]
```

How do I transform the mocked object into a mocked resource object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of toEqual, use a custom jasmine matcher :

Jasmine 1:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.addMatchers({
    toEqualData: function(expect) {
      return angular.equals(expect, this.actual);
    }
});
```

});

Jasmine 2:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toEqualData: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return { pass: angular.equals(actual, expected) };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

source : [How do I get a resource from an Angular.js module for a jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486115/how-do-i-get-a-resource-from-an-angular-js-module-for-a-jasmine-test/16487071#16487071)
(from Misko Hevery, creator of angular)